# typescript create default value for nested optional object type

Tags: typescript

I have a type `MyType`

```
type MyType = {
  a?: {c: string},
  b?: {e: string},
}
```

that contains optional nested objects. I want to create a function `getDefaultValue` that accepts a key `K` of `MyType` and returns a default representation of the nested object that is specified by key `K`.

```
function getDefaultValue<K extends keyof MyType>(key: K):Required<MyType>[K] {
  if (key === 'a') return {c: 'hello'}
  return {e: 'hello'}
}

const variable: Required<MyType>['a'] = getDefaultValue('a')
```

I get the following typescript errors:

```
TS2322: Type '{ c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Required<MyType>[K]'.
  Type '{ c: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ c: string; } & { e: string; }'.
    Property 'e' is missing in type '{ c: string; }' but required in type '{ e: string; }'.
TS2322: Type '{ e: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Required<MyType>[K]'.
  Type '{ e: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ c: string; } & { e: string; }'.
    Property 'c' is missing in type '{ e: string; }' but required in type '{ c: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching the types of returned values with generic parameters can be a bit tricky, but in this case you can avoid the problem altogether by putting the defaults in an object

```
const defaults = {
  a: { c: 'hello' },
  b: { e: 'hello' },
}
```

and declaring `getDefaultValue` like this:

```
function getDefaultValue<K extends keyof MyType>(key: K) {
  return defaults[key]
}

const test1 = getDefaultValue('a') // inferred type: {c: string}
const test2 = getDefaultValue('b') // inferred type: {e: string}
```

Missing default values will be signalled by a type error at `defaults[key]`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoEMD8AXOlAMZEDOwATgJYB2A5lAL4A0WUARocRBdfSZsMzDBhIB7OpSgATCADMcAVwA2wclFSZsOImlJEA5AAsIq1RKMt22Tvqh8op85evDRGBcrolgNKSgGCGAAEUUVdQA1HFVlCAAeAGlHAA9gCDpZTQBrCBAJBVgEJAA%20AAo8kCIkgEp0DioQ5So6OQi1DQBtKoBdETFJaWAoDMoARi0gkPClTpi4iHKjHCN6gHp1qHoFCCom2VGkfTIoSlpGUSGZMeAAJingsI7o2PjlzjWoTe26Xf2IIdQJB9E5zoJPNcRgA3HC0HCcVROABKEAAjsoaAcEnBEJBSl0VkZeo8Zi9gAt3kTakA)

Comment: We are using strict linter rules which oblige to set the return type of the function. Is there any type (except any =))  which describes it or is it just working because of inferred types?

Comment: @AndriiDobrianskiy You can use the `Required<MyType>[K]` return-type signature from the question and it will still work.

Comment: Thanks, still, things like `const test1 = getDefaultValue('a' as "a" | "b") ` does not work . But it is for sure reasonable.

Comment: @AndriiDobrianskiy Typically in functions like this the key will have a literal type because `getDefaultValue` will get called with a constant string argument, but if even it's a union, you'll get a union of possible result types, which seems the desired type to me. You indeed won't be able to statically infer the actual type from the value at run-time in case the type is too wide, but you don't really need to for this function to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to do it with TypeScript as you are trying to use runtime values instead of types to create a generic.

Please consider the following example and try to answer the questions:

```
const key: 'a' | 'b' = 'a';
const variable: Required<MyType>['a'] = getDefaultValue(key)
```

1. How to guarantee that the result type is basically `Required<MyType>['a']` not `Required<MyType>['b']`
2. How typescript should understand that `K extends keyof MyType` is a type of one value?

P.S. As a hack you can specify `any` as a return type, but it is not something that you need to do with TypeScript

```
type MyType = {
  a?: {c: string},
  b?: {e: string},
}

type MyKeys = keyof MyType;

function getDefaultValue(key: MyKeys): any {
  if (key === 'a') {
    return {c: 'hello'};
  }
  return {e: 'hello'}
}

const variable: Required<MyType>['a'] = getDefaultValue('a')
```

P.P.S. I would recommend creating a function that will return a default value for the whole object and simply grab what you need

```
function getDefaultValue(): Required<MyType> {
  return {
    a: {c: 'hello'},
    b: {e: 'hello'},
  };
}
const variable = getDefaultValue().a;
```